# Unsafe javascript error because of wrong query param in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://someurl.com?someparam={{ angularvariable }}');">{{ angularvariable }}</a>
```

Lets say angularvariable = stack. When I'm trying to use the above, I get unsafe javascript error. In the query params, I see `someparam=stack');`

This must be the problem for unsafe javascript error, but how to solve this ?

Below is newPopup function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    "use strict";
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I you are using angular this is not the best way to go about it.

I would use a function in the controller and use ng-click to call the function

in your controller

```
$scope.newPopup = function(url){
   //Popup code here
}
```

In you veiw

```
<span ng-click="newPopup('http://someurl.com?someparam='+angularvariable)">{{angularvariable}}</span>
```